# runtime error (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i would be happy to know why i got this error for the problem http://www.codechef.com/problems/AXR1P2 in codechef.com and my code is...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int *num=0,n=0,i=0,max=0;char *s="";
int sum[9]={1,5,14,20,25,31,32,38,39},dsum[9]={1,7,8,14,19,25,26,32,33},unitdig=0;
do
{
  gets(s);
*(num+i)=(int)atoi(s);
i++;
}while(*s!='#');
max=i;
for(i=0;i<max-1;i++)
{
 n=*(num+i);
 if(n>10)
  unitdig=33*(n/10-1)+39+dsum[(n%10)-1];
 else
  unitdig=sum[(n%10)-1];
   printf("%d\n",unitdig%10);
}
 getchar();
return 0;}
```

Comment: In the future, it will be easier for us to help you (and easier for you to help yourself) if you try to debug it on your own first before dumping your code here. You should (in a copy, with the original backed up somewhere) eliminate code until you've narrowed down what causes the error you're getting, and then try to figure out why that error is occurring. We can help you faster and more thoroughly that way.

Comment: Also it would also be very helpful for people answering your question if the source code was at least formatted

Answer (score 3):

Several errors:

```
char * s = "";
...
gets(s);
```

you are trying to read into  a string literal, you want:

```
char s[SOMESIZE];
```

And you have not initialised num to point to anything, so at:

```
*(num+i)=(int)atoi(s);
```

you are dereferencing a null pointer. There are probably other issues - these are two I spotted (almost) immediately.

Comment: I think the segfault comes at `gets(s)` personally, but that's also a bad one.

Comment: @Chris Yes, I spotted that immediately after I hit the send button.

Comment: Also note that the OP should **never** use `gets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an int pointer (num) that does not point to an allocated space. Any access to this pointer will lead to unexpected behavior.